# What should TResult be when using public async Task to return json response from API HTTP Post

Tags: c#, http-post, flurl

Account Service:

```
public async Task<string> PostRegistrationToApi(NameValueCollection form)
        try
        {
            string str = await url.WithHeaders(new { Accept = "application /json", User_Agent = "Flurl" }).PostJsonAsync(myDictionary).ReceiveJson();
            return str;
        }
```

This is how it looks like in interface:

```
public interface IAccountService
{
    Task<string> PostRegistrationToApi(NameValueCollection form);
```

This is my controller view:

```
                string str = await _accountService.PostRegistrationToApi(myform);
                return RedirectToAction("Register");
```

This is the error message I get:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' to 'string'

I could not figure out how to solve this error. Can someone tell me what this error message means and how to fix it? At first, I thought it's TResult type issue but seems like even if I change the variable to string type, consistent with TResult. I still get the same error. Thanks!

Comment: You could return a `Task<dynamic>`, but dynamic objects are often not to be taken lightly and in general for C# I would still recommend creating an actual concrete class into which you would deserialize the JSON and then return that object.

Comment: @David Do you have an example of how to deserialize the JSON in this case? I tried to get StatusCode from this.

Comment: What does a response from the service actually look like? Could you post an example response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because `ReceiveJson` returns a `dynamic`, not a string. This allows you to work with the result as an object with properties without having to declare a matching class. This is handy for quick & dirty JSON responses where you know the shape of the response won't change, but you give up compile-time type checking, so in most cases I recommend creating a matching class and using `RecieveJson<T>`.

If you really want to get a string back, you can use `ReceiveString` instead. If you're just forwarding the response off to something else or dumping it to a log or something that can be useful. But if you need to somehow *process* the JSON result I'd recommend using `ReceiveJson` or `ReceiveJson<T>` so you can work with the result as a C# object.